# Python CSV Filter with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, filter

I've been sitting on this problem for a few days now.
I have a CSV with about 400 columns and I need to filter them by country. Unfortunately I don't have a header for the CSV so I added one myself. Now I want to filter by it but it always writes me only the first line and does not filter it properly. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks
[Picture of New CSV with problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPZeX.png)
[Picture of CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeUNT.png)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv



def checkcsv(pfadfile1, pfadfile2, Land):
  with open(pfadfile1, 'r') as f_in:
    with open(pfadfile2, 'w') as f_outfile:
        writer = csv.writer(f_outfile, delimiter="|")
        writer.writerow(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Location", "12", "13", "14", "15"])

        f_out = csv.writer(f_outfile, escapechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

        for line in f_in:
            line = line.strip()
            row = []
            if Land in line:
                row.append(line)
                f_out.writerow(row)
  def load_source(Land):
    with open("SILNOVA_DE.csv", "r") as f:
      with open("SILNOVA_DE_FINAL.csv", "w") as isfile:
        df = pd.read_csv("SILNOVA_DE.csv", sep='|', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
        df = df[(df["Location"] == Land)]

        #df.to_csv(pfadfile2, index=False, sep='|')

        writer = csv.writer(isfile, delimiter='|', lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow(df)

        print(df)




def main():
# show()
checkcsv("Beispiel.csv", "SILNOVA_DE.csv", "AT")
ReadWriteconfig_file("SILNOVA_DE.csv")
load_source("AT")


main()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: your rows should all have the same number of columns.

Comment: So i must give all columns a number and than i can Filter them?